# Adding data last in linkedlist

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am trying to add data in the last a link list. Here is my code.
This is my Linked list class:

```
public class LinkedList {
        Node head;

        private static class Node {
            int data;
            Node pointer;

            public Node(int data) {
                this.data=data;
                pointer=null;
            }
        }
```

this method is for appending data in last.

```
  public void append(int new_data){
        Node new_node=new Node (new_data);

        if (head==null){
            head=new Node(new_data);

        }
        Node last_node=head;
         new_node.pointer=null;
        while (last_node.pointer !=null){
            last_node=last_node.pointer;
            last_node.pointer=new_node;

        }
     }
```

this method is to print the data.

```
public void printData(){
    Node print_Node;
    print_Node=head;
    while (print_Node !=null){
        System.out.print(print_Node.data+" ");
        print_Node=print_Node.pointer;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList obj=new LinkedList();

    obj.append(10);
    obj.append(100);
    obj.printData();

  }
}
```

Where is the problem in my code? It only prints 10.

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: I actually could not find problem in my logic :\ so could not started debugging :\

Comment: You can start debugging any code that compiles (or even that doesn't, see [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)).  Considering you said yours is printing, it must compile; thus, you can debug.

Comment: Debugging means to follow each and any step your program is taking. Everybody can do that.

Comment: And hint: study java coding style guidelines. You don't use _ in variable names! And "pointer" is A) actually incorrect B) simply a bad name. Call it "nextNode"; and everybody knows what the thing is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while (last_node.pointer !=null){
  last_node=last_node.pointer;
  last_node.pointer=new_node; // this line ... bad!
```

You are using last_node to iterate **all** the nodes in your list.
And while you are iterating; you are setting the pointers of all those nodes ... to point to the newly created node. But you should only do that once, when you have reached the end of your list!

Not sure why that keeps your first entry in; but well, your code to append  is definitely not correct.

Comment: Exactly. Feel free to accept my answer then ;-) ... glad I could help. But still: check out java style guides, and train yourself in "naming".

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS OUT

public class linked_list {

```
Node head;

private static class Node

{
    int data;
    Node pointer;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        pointer = null;
    }
}

    public void append(int new_data)
    {
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
        //new_node.pointer = null;  No need to set pointer to null as it is already null in your constructor.

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(new_data);
        }

        Node last_node = head; // Its okay To not change head , good practise.
        while (last_node.pointer != null)
        {
            last_node = last_node.pointer;
        }
        // I think here was the error, your the linked list was not adding only one element , Because while loop
       // got terminated just it reaches null i.e not executing the below line.
        // So put it after while loop, wen you have reached the NULL.
        last_node.pointer = new_node; // line ERROR

    }
    public void printData(){
        Node print_Node;
        print_Node=head;
        while (print_Node !=null){
            System.out.print(print_Node.data+" ");
            print_Node = print_Node.pointer;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        linked_list obj=new linked_list();

        obj.append(10);
        obj.append(100);
        obj.append(898);
        obj.append(8334);
        obj.append(118334);
        obj.append(833400);
        obj.append(83340043);

        obj.printData();

    }

}
```

Comment: I have just figured it out. Yes "last_node.pointer=new_node;" should be out of while loop.

Comment: Hint: that is actually not a good answer: just dropping code without further explanations is not good style.

Comment: Sorry, but I have mentioned the error and explained it in the comments.